# when to use repository, service or only dao in a project?

Tags: java, spring

The question is exactly like the title says: when and how to use it or repository and service are all the same, just two words for the same thing? I saw a project where the developer uses a dao interface and a service interface that do almost the same thing. Why not just keep the dao?

Comment: Please go through with the following explanation given : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669760/what-is-main-purpose-of-interface-for-service-and-dao-in-spring-framework

Answer (score 1):

It is a way to organise and structure you code in a maintainable, readable and clean style.

To keep it very simple:

**Controller**:
Provides the interface if you use REST API. It injects the Services.

**Service**:
The class where the business logic is located. It injects the Repositories.

**Repository**:
Used for data access. Like a JpaRepository or with JDBC-Templates.

Answer (score -1):

The `Controller`, `Service` and `Repository` classes are part of the `Three Layer Codebase` with the purpose of structuring one's code.

The **Controller** manages the model and presents the view.

The **Service** class contains business logic (a calculation or decision-making process) and acts as a "connecter" between the Controller class and Repository class.

The **Repository** class makes **CRUD** operations (**C**reate, **R**ead, **U**pdate, **D**elete) to the datastore.

---

**The Process:**

1. `Controller` calls the `Service` Class
2. `Service` class calls the `Repository` class
3. `Repository` class gets the data and sends it via the `Service` class back to the `Controller` class

---

So, whenever you are starting a new project I recommend you to create separate folders for the respective class (`Controller`, `Repository` and `Service`) to have a clear structure in your code.